# Can part of single wave of EMR have ionizing effect?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

i write this post instead of [another post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397879/2451), which got -2 votes and was deleted. i even did not expect that it would (or will?) be deleted.

when i read on https://www.quora.com/ about harmfulness of emr, wifi etc, i see people say that wifi is not ionizing emr, thus it does not push out electrons out of atom; uv emr is the lowest frequency emr which is ionizing.

then, i think:

1. can a single part of a single wave of emr have ionizing effect?
2. if it can, then, can several low frequency emr combined create such a single wave part, like of high-frequency, harmful, ionizing radiation?

for example, you can look plots at https://www.wolframalpha.com/ . compare plots for:

1. "y=sin(x) , x from 0 to pi/200" - this represents low-frequency radiation; it goes from 0 only to 0.015 in 0 - 0.015 timeframe.
2. "y=sin(100x) , x from 0 to pi/200" - this represents high-frequency radiation; it goes from 0 to 1.0 in 0 - 0.015 timeframe.
3. "y=100sin(x) , x from 0 to pi/200" - this represents 100 low-frequency radiations combined so that they have come with low points together and high points together at same moment of time, by accident; in this moment of time, it goes from 0 to 1.5 in 0 - 0.015 timeframe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_wave

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to visualize this from a photon perspective. The  energy of a single photon is simply Planck's constant x frequency. 
Ionizination simply means an electron has been ejected from an atom. 
The claim is that photons with wavelengths higher than UV (frequency lower) do not have enough energy to cause ionization.

The question you have, translated into photon language is "cannot multiple photons be absorbed by an electron causing ionization?" Two photons together may have more energy than a UV photon.
In principle such absorption is possible but the probability is extremely low. These are called nonlinear effects. Experiments of this type have been performed using high energy lasers. There are enough photons and so two or more of them can be at the same location and be absorbed by a single electron.

But this is practically impossible in everyday situations. All the claims of danger from wifi or mobiles contradict basic physics as much as astrology. (There will be quite a bit of opposition to this statement however)

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic radiation is an emergent phenomenon from zillions of [photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon), elementary point particles. Atoms can be ionized by photons, which can transfer the energy of $h\nu$, where $\nu$ is the frequency of the light that the photon is a part of.

For the individual photon to transfer its energy to an electron and thus have an ionized atom, it has to have high enough energy,i.e. frequency, which the infrared and microwave electromagnetic radiation does not have.

> can a single part of a single wave of emr have ionizing effect?

The parts of the electromagnetic waves are called photons.

> if it can, then, can several low frequency emr combined create such a single wave part, like of high-frequency, harmful, ionizing radiation?

photons are quantum mechanical entities, and quantum mechanics works with probabilities. The probability of two low non ionizing photon to hit the same atom and transfer their energy to ionize the atom is possible but very improbable, very special conditions have to happen which doe not exist in WiFi and infrared.

The link you give gives general links, no plots. Rest assured though that it is very improbable that two photons will ionize an atom, unless under special conditions.

Comment: i gave request strings to copy. i could give urls: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsin(x)+,+x+from+0+to+pi%2F200 .

Comment: It is not useful, the addition has to be happen at the quantum level.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the photoelectric effect. It's experimentally observed that light whose frequency is high enough will basicly knock electrons off of atoms, while light below that frequency will produce no more electrons than statisticly normal.

So we can say confidently that wifi is not ionizing EMR.

However, the question whether it has biological effects is different. It does not depend on it being ionizing EMR.

As a minor example, consider vision. This important biochemical result does not depend on ionization. A complicated protein, rhodopsin, can twist into a different shape, changing a covalent chemical bond, and that has big effects which the cell can detect.

Similarly photosynthesis. Light that is too low-energy to ionize can still be trapped and collect enough energy to store as a chemical bond. The protein that does this is sometimes connected to other big proteins that act as antennas and collect more light energy of other frequencies.

UV light is ionizing, and your DNA contains some sequences where two thymidines are side by side. UV can make them cross-link. There is a repair enzyme which unlinks them, that is catalyzed by blue light. The blue light doesn't have enough energy to ionize them, but it has enough to undo the crosslink under precisely the right circumstances.

Infrared light does not ionize. But it can make organic sub-assemblies vibrate. That vibration can be detected, and organic chemists can use it to identify unknown compounds. They can look at the IR absorption spectrum and say "There's a carboxyl group, there's an ethoxy group", etc. Basicly they are heating the compound a bit.

When you get down to wifi frequencies, they are not vibrating methyl groups, they are vibrating whole proteins and whole RNA molecules etc. If a protein gets vibrated too much it will "denature". It folds up just so while it is first being built, and if it gets shaken apart it likely won't fold back the same way. Proteins tend to have different parts that each fold together themselves and then fit together with each other, and those can be vibrated apart. Sometimes proteins are made of separate subunits that hold together with van der Waals force and hydrogen bonding, and those can get separated and drift apart. Similarly many RNA molecules get folded together in specific ways and can get unfolded. On the other hand some RNA molecules need to be unfolded but sometimes do kink together, and they might work better if they are getting vibrated loose.

These molecules will usually not be affected much by microwaves because the microwaves are smeared across a big range of frequencies and so there isn't much power in any one frequency.

Also, there's a big variety of proteins with similar resonant frequencies, so masers will tend to be absorbed by so many different kinds of proteins that no one of them gets much of the energy. And water absorbs many frequencies, though there are some water absorption minima.

Proteins are made of many different subunits and they tend to have lots of different resonant frequencies, so the chance that one frequency will damage a protein is no more likely than that soldiers marching across a bridge will make the bridge collapse. Bridges also have many different resonant frequencies.

But there are many thousands of different kinds of proteins in your body, and a few of them might particularly absorb a particular wifi frequency, and wifi frequencies tend to be kind of specific. A few proteins might be affected, they could be permanently inactivated, or temporarily, or might have increased function which could disrupt cellular control mechanisms. Still, of the many thousands of proteins some of them will not be important and if those are affected it won't matter much.

So in conclusion, as a tentative first approximation, we can say that wifi is not ionizing radiation and it has no effect on cells beyond the same amount of heat. People who speculate about biological effects are crackpots who go entirely beyond the data. Wifi frequencies have been scientifically proven to be 100% safe.

Or maybe that's taking it a bit too far. I think it would be prudent to at least avoid frequencies which are water absorption minima.